# how to open JavaScript widget photos in lightbox2?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, lightbox2, panoramio

i have a [panaramio JavaScript widget](http://digitalwander.blogspot.com/2013/11/united-arab-emirates.html) when i click on photo it open in new tab.how to open it in lightbox2?

It is okay if you give me example code to open image in blogger default lightbox.

this is my code

```
<script src="http://www.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1&hl=en" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">

  #div_attr_ex .panoramio-wapi-images {
    background-color: transparent;
  } 
</style>
<div id="div_attr_ex" style="float: center; margin: 5px 10px;">

<div id="photo_widget_id_b">
</div>
<div id="photo_widget_id_c">
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sand = {'tag':'Saudi Arabia'};
  var sandRequest = new panoramio.PhotoRequest(sand);
  var attr_ex_list_options = {
    'width': 880,
    'height': 630,
    'columns': 4,
    'rows': 3,
    'croppedPhotos': false,
    'disableDefaultEvents': [panoramio.events.EventType.PHOTO_CLICKED],
    'orientation': panoramio.PhotoListWidgetOptions.Orientation.VERTICAL,
    'attributionStyle': panoramio.tos.Style.HIDDEN};
  var attr_ex_list_widget = new panoramio.PhotoListWidget(
    'photo_widget_id_b', sandRequest, attr_ex_list_options);

  var attr_ex_attr_options = {'width': 310};
  var attr_ex_attr_widget = new panoramio.TermsOfServiceWidget(
    'photo_widget_id_c', attr_ex_attr_options);

function MaximizeWindow(hWnd){
    hWnd.moveTo(0,0);
    hWnd.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
}

  function onListPhotoClicked(event) {
  var position = event.getPosition();
var photo=event.getPhoto();

    if(photo){
        MaximizeWindow(window.open('http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/'+photo.getPhotoId()+'.jpg'));
    }

}

panoramio.events.listen(
    attr_ex_list_widget, panoramio.events.EventType.PHOTO_CLICKED,
    function(e) { onListPhotoClicked(e); });

  attr_ex_list_widget.setPosition(0);
 attr_ex_list_widget.enablePreviousArrow(false);
  attr_ex_list_widget.enableNextArrow(false);

</script>
```

[Its demo is here.](http://travelwitheyes.blogspot.com/2013/11/saudi-arabia.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have see your link and to open the images in light box you have to change the href attribute of the anchor tag wrapping the image. Follow jquery lightbox tutorial here          http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ 
or you can choose any of the following option here
http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/lightbox/
its simple and straight.

Comment: this is my code and it has no anchor tag  onListPhotoClicked2(event) {
    var position = event.getPosition();
var photo=event.getPhoto();
    if(photo){
        MaximizeWindow(window.open('http://static.panoramio.com/photos/large/'+photo.getPhotoId()+'.jpg'));
    }
    
}
function MaximizeWindow(hWnd){
    hWnd.moveTo(0,0);
    hWnd.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
}
 
  panoramio.events.listen(
    attr_ex_photo_widget, panoramio.events.EventType.PHOTO_CLICKED,
    function(e) { onListPhotoClicked2(e); });

Comment: ok, so you are not adding any anchor links to the images. these links added by google itself. The solution might be altering all the anchor tags and changing the href attributes or try this event http://www.panoramio.com/api/widget/api.html#photo-object to trigger your lightbox feature it might work

Comment: Sure,will try but need the widget code(the code which you have downloaded from panoramio) which you have integrated in your website so that I can try to crack the issue.

Comment: my simple question is How can i open a lightbox by a function call ?

Comment: follow http://visuallightbox.com/rq/click-one-image-to-start-the-simple-lightbox-1b.html its simple. But for further reference you may like to implement http://wijmo.com/topic/how-to-open-lightbox-picture-with-onclick-event-rather-than-href/